# How to use multiple processes in Webpack?

Tags: webpack

**I am a beginner in the webpack and I need to do the following:**

I have several 'main' typescript and sass files. I would like to compile in just one **"yarn webpack"** all these types of files, however there is a simple **compilation / transpilation** rule.

**Rule:**
1) There are several TS / SASS files and each of them must come with their respective saved folder names.

2) The files must be minified

3) I should be able to save the mined files with their respective extensions in two different places: "dist" and "public".

**MY CONFIG:**

```
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = [
    {
        mode: "production",
        entry: {
            indicators: path.resolve(__dirname, 'typescript', 'pages', 'Indicators.ts')
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].min.js',
            path:       path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'js'),
            publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src',  'js'),
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    use: 'ts-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                }
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
        },
        optimization: {
            minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin({
                uglifyOptions: {
                    extractComments: false,
                    warnings: false,
                    parse: {},
                    compress: {},
                    mangle: true,
                    output: null,
                    toplevel: false,
                    nameCache: null,
                    ie8: false,
                    keep_fnames: false,
                  },
            })]
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: you want to bundle a bunch of ts and scss files into a single js and single css file?

Comment: Yes, but there is a rule in this ..

For example: I have the flags page and I will insert only the sass / ts (x and y) files and on the Test page only the sass / ts (z and f) files. I would like to know in the webpack how I set it up for this template.

Comment: so you need 2 entry points? one for flag page and another for testpage?

Comment: you want a separate js bundle for flag page and testpage?

Comment: @divine yes.....